# How can we backstack activities when back button is pressed ? i.e Pop up activities from the stack

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

Simply , When activity 'B' is stacked after activity 'A'.Want activity 'A' to resume while back button is pressed in activity 'B'. Don't want activity'A' to restart using intent , want to resume activity 'A'.

Comment: I got the solution boys !!
Simply, Overriding with method onBackPressed and finishing the current activity. This worked me fine !!
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can influence this behaviour using various launchmode flags. See the official documentation about this topic:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

Comment: Thanks for your Time. I got the solution !! Simply, Overriding with method onBackPressed and finishing the current activity. This worked me fine !! @Override public void onBackPressed() { finish(); }

Answer (score 0):

You can override onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) and write the application state values which you want to save as a Bundle parameter like this:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
  // killed and restarted.
  savedInstanceState.putBoolean("X", true);
  savedInstanceState.putString("Y", "Sultan");
  // etc.
}
```

The Bundle will get passed in to onCreate() and also onRestoreInstanceState() where you'd extract the values like this:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.

  int x = savedInstanceState.getInt("X");
  String y = savedInstanceState.getString("Y");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Time. I got the solution !! Simply, Overriding with method onBackPressed and finishing the current activity. This worked me fine !! @Override public void onBackPressed() { finish(); }